# create-react-app local and dev environment variables

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have `.env.local` with

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASEURL=http://localhost:8080/
```

and `.env.development` with

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASEURL=http://deployedserverurl:8080/
```

how do I select the correct env file on start?
As it is now, it prefers the dev env file over the local.

`npm start --env=local` doesnt seem to work, am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Environment variables are imported depending on the current environment. There is a built in special environment variable with `create-react-app` called `NODE_ENV`. In summary, when you run `npm start` the `NODE_ENV` variable is set to development and set to production when running a `npm run build`. Therefore, if you create a `.env.development` in the root of your project, when you run `npm start` these variable definitions will be searched for in the environment.

Also, ensure you're using them correctly by using `process.env.REACT_APP_APP_BACKEND_BASEURL`.

If you need more information regarding all of the details about the different type of .env files, check these out from the [React Docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables):

`env`: Default.

`.env.local`: Local overrides. **This file is loaded for all environments except test.**

`.env.development`, `.env.test`, `.env.production`: Environment-specific settings.

`.env.development.local`, `.env.test.local`, `.env.production.local`: Local overrides of environment-specific settings.

Comment: but what about accessing dev url without having to build it? I mean different env variables depending on my needs, will I have to need to manually edit them on the fly?

Comment: You can actually perform a check on NODE_ENV in your code if you need to only use certain variables during production or dev to prevent manually editing your variables.

Comment: The correct link for adding customer values is here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/